# Poisson process, tossing and expectation

Tags: probability

In a random process, total number of tosses are defined by Poisson(2). Each toss is independent, having probability of success as 2/3. What is the expected number of successes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of successes is itself Poisson-distributed, with parameter $2\cdot\frac23=\frac43$, so the expected number of successes is $\frac43$.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ denotes the number of successes and $T$ the number of tosses then for every nonnegative integer $t$: $$\mathbb E[S\mid T=t]=\frac23t$$

This observation allows us to conclude that:$$\mathbb E[S\mid T]=\frac23T$$

Then we can find the expectation of $S$ by applying the rules:$$
\mathbb ES=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[S\mid T]]=\mathbb E\frac23T==\frac43$$